# Textbox autocomplete with mysql as database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I am trying to do the text box autocomplete by using the code below, but it gives the error

```
ERROR :"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

on this line:

```
for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
```

Can anyone please help me?

```
private void tbMemberName_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbMemberName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    tbMemberName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namec = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    //string search ="%"+ tbMemberName.Text +"%";
    //string @Name = tbMemberName.Text; 
    String sql =
        @"SELECT DISTINCT(member_Firstname +''+ member_Lastname) AS Name FROM members WHERE Name  Like '%'+tbMemberName.Text+'%'";
    DataTable dt = MemberFormHelper.GetData(sql, mf);
    if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            namec.Add(dt.Rows[count][Name].ToString());
        }
    }
    tbMemberName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namec;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that `dt.Rows` is not NULL ?

Comment: `dt` could be null and thats why the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dt` is null, prolly (unless u have a record in ur table with the following name 'tbMemberName.Text')... I guess so -  `tbMemberName` is a `TextBox`, so if you are trying to pass its value to the sql string instead of

`@"SELECT DISTINCT(member_Firstname +''+ member_Lastname) AS Name FROM members WHERE Name  Like '%'+tbMemberName.Text+'%'";`

u have to write

`@"SELECT DISTINCT(member_Firstname +''+ member_Lastname) AS Name FROM members WHERE Name  Like '%"+tbMemberName.Text+"%'";`

u have just misused quotation marks.

Comment: the data does not loaded into the name collection at this statementnamecollection.Add(dt.Rows[0]["member_Firstname"].ToString()); would you pls help me

Comment: so finally u are inside the `for` loop. if u are still using `SELECT DISTINCT(member_Firstname +''+ member_Lastname) AS Name` statement `dt.Rows[0]["member_Firstname"]` will fail. as there is no `"member_Firstname"` column. Column u want to address is "Name" (the alias u gave), so instead use `dt.Rows[0]["Name"]`. if there's still problem post ur new `select` statement

Answer (score 1):

I used this code based on the codes of msdn microsoft and of sir P.K. i think you should consider this

First I insert these codes in the form_load 
ex:

```
this.cmbSchool.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.cmbSchool.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

To access the textchanged property in my example I used comboBox instead of Textbox (I inserted them outside forms and used it as universal var to be accessed by combobox1_textchange later)

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
```

if you are using Mysql I used this (also inserted in form_load) to save the data in collection

```
        string querySelect = "SELECT * FROM tblschools";
        MySqlCommand commandSelect = new MySqlCommand(querySelect, connectionMain);
        MySqlDataReader reader = commandSelect.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string type = reader[1].ToString();
            cmbSchool.Items.Add(type); //data inserted in combobox list (dropdownstyle in c# dropdown) so that I can still type
            collection.Add(type); //data inserted in collection so that it will be autocomplete when you type keywords
        }
        reader.Close();
```

Then the last step is I inserted this code in cmbSchool_TextChanged

```
this.cmbSchool.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection; //everytime you type it will initiate and gather data from the collection
```

P.S. this is my first time to post sorry for my explanation and bad coding but hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think DT must be null and its actually the line above the for loop which fails